# What is the standard way to handle url-mapping for JavaServer Faces?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

All the tutorials I have seen seem to use `*.jsf`, `*.faces`, or `/<directory_name>/*` for the url-pattern in the Java Server faces servlet mapping. Is there some official sun-recommended naming convention or de-facto standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended conventions are in the [JSF 1.2 specification](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/reference/api/index.html).

Section 10.1.2:

> When
>   using prefix mapping, the following
>   mapping is recommended, but not
>   required:

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name> faces-servlet-name </servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

> When using extension mapping the
>   following mapping is recommended, but
>   not required:

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name> faces-servlet-name </servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I edited the question to include '.jsf' so you may want to edit the part of the question where you say 'Those' are the recommended conventions. Thanks for finding that though.